# Value of $a_2+a_6+a_{10}+\cdots+a_{42}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

If $(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^9)^4(x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^9)=\sum_{r=1}^{45} a_rx^r ,$ then what is the value of $a_2+a_6+a_{10}+\cdots+a_{42}$

Comment: See my comments under [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597578/find-a-0-frac-12-a-1-a-2a-3-a-4-a-5a-6-cdots-pm-a-n), self-deleted since.

Comment: I get $22500$ by making a spreadsheet.  Copy down is a wonderful thing. 
 That is suspicious for being $150^2$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expansion++(1%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6%2Bx%5E7%2Bx%5E8%2Bx%5E9)%5E4(x%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6%2Bx%5E7%2Bx%5E8%2Bx%5E9)

Answer (score 5):

Calling your expression $f(x)$, we have
$$ a_2 + a_6 + \ldots + a_{42} = \dfrac{f(1) + f(-1) - f(i) - f(-i)}{4}
$$
Now $f(1) = 9 \cdot 10^4$, $f(-1) = 0$, $f(i) = -4 i$ and $f(-i) = 4i$, so
this is $(9 \cdot 10^4)/4 = 22500$.